# datatables PDF - Export without border only after certain row

Tags: html, pdf, datatables, pdfmake

Is there anyway to remove the border after certain rows when exporting PDF from datatables. Example as below

1. This is the datatables shown on the browser with the formatting

[image: Browser DT]

2. This is the exported PDF from the datatables above

[image: Exported PDF]

Is there any way that i can remove all borders in the exported PDF after the `AVG (WE)` row to show the same as what i see in the datatables shows in the 1st picture?

I have been trying to find this out for quite some time, but cannot find any working code. Really appreciate any solution i can get. Thank you so much

Comment: Show the code what have you tried?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava the code i tried either remove all border or it is showing all borders

Comment: Cannot just help if cannot see what you did

Comment: The code which resulted in these screenshots is missing, which makes this questions quite abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do this by appending captions into the datatables, it will show the caption after all data is populated out in the datatables and when trying to export it, it will only show in the last page. Add in the caption code right before your datatables js

```
$('#dtBasicExample').append('<br/>');
      $('#dtBasicExample').append('<caption style="caption-side: bottom">\nInsert Caption Here</caption>');

$('#dtBasicExample').dataTable({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'd have to add two tables, because a table either has a border or it has none.
See https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/tables for reference.

Comment: datatables doesnt allow multiple tables export